# Cypress with Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, cypress

We are in a process of migrating existing Protractor scripts(with Jasmine Framework) to Cypress.
I would like to know if we can use the Jasmine in Cypress also. As, Cypress by default uses Mocha.., so need a clarification if we can install Jasmine dependences along with Cypress to define the tests with Framework.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Cypress modifies/patches the Mocha hooks like `beforeEach()` and also the chai `expect()` to work with their framework.

Is there anything about Jasmine that you don't get out of the box with Cypress? I believe the `expect()` syntax may be different, if you have too many Jasmine-style expectations to change you may be able to add custom Chai expressions so that they work without modification.